# Date Column in Power BI spiting into 4 columns

Tags: powerbi

I'm using Power BI, pulling data from a SQL server, but for a column containing date, it keeps splitting into 4 other columns when I try and show it in a table:

`Year` | `Quarter` | `Month` | `Day`

Has anyone had this issue before?

Note: Under modeling, when selecting that field I did try placing Data Type as Date. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Power BI made a date hierarchy from this field. If you do not want this, right click it in the designer and uncheck Date hierarchy from the menu:
[image]